# Nuance between said to him/told him

Tags: grammar, imperative-sentences, direct-speech

Imperative: She said to him "Buy milk"

Infinitive: She told him to buy milk.

Couldn't it have been,
**She said to him to buy milk**

Although **said to him** doesn't sound ungrammatical, it doesn't sound natural either.

But why?

Why don't I get that strong feeling of command in **said to him** like I would in direct imperative speech i.e, "Buy Milk"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the broad fields of meaning of "**say**" and "**tell** partly overlap, they do not completely overlap. The way in which they overlap is in the sense of communicating.

> He told her that the car would be expensive to repair

and

> He said to her that the car would be expensive to repair

normally mean exactly the same thing.

However, one sense of "**tell**" is "**order**." The verb "**say**" does not in itself have the connotation of "**order**" (although context may supply that connotation). However, "**tell**" does not necessarily mean "**order**."

To sum up, "**tell**" is sometimes, but not always, a synonym for "**order** whereas "**say**" is not.

Comment: and in my given sentence **buying milk** is an order. So it's better to use told here. Right?

Comment: Nobody says "Buy Milk" with a capital B and a capital M.

Comment: I did that to put more emphasis 

Comment: @michaelharvey. But B has to be capital.  First word of the quote has to be capitalized when you are quoting the whole text.

Comment: OK, I'll let you have the B, but not the M.

Comment: @SGG You asked "and in my given sentence buying milk is an order. So it's better to use told here. Right?" You are right on.